# How to redirect every requests to sub.sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com? (Azure cloud service)

Tags: iis, azure

I'm trying to configure my web.config to redirect all the requests to http://sub.sub.domain.com to http://sub.domain.com. My project is hosted in a cloud service in Windows Azure.

Here is what I've tried (but not working).

```
<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name="Redirect sub.sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"
                    pattern="^sub\.sub\.domain\.com$"
                    negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect"
                    url="http://sub.domain.com/{R:1}"
                    redirectType="Permanent" />
         </rule>
      </rules>      
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Anyone can help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your web.config to include the following:

```
<rule name="My redirection">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub.sub.domain.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://sub.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy but it doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know if it's because of Azure or not but the redirect does not work. :(

Comment: Hi Jacques, is sub.sub.domain.com bound to your Azure deployment?

Comment: If you mean that the domain is configured inside Azure then no. In my DNS server, I added a CNAME record for sub.sub.domain.com to point to mydomain.cloudapp.net. I also added a CNAME record for sub.domain.com to point to the same cloudapp.net address.

Comment: To make sure that this works as expected I've just deployed a test solution to a new Azure Web Role and the suggested rule worked fine.

Comment: I will have to do some more testing tomorrow then. Thank you for your input Andy. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally went with the solution to handle this in the BeginRequest event in global.asax. Here's the code I used:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  if( this.Request.Url.Host.StartsWith( "sub.sub.domain.com" ) )
  {
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder( this.Request.Url );
    uriBuilder.Host = this.Request.Url.Host.Replace( "sub.sub.domain.com", "sub.cuisinaviva.com" );

    this.Response.RedirectPermanent( uriBuilder.ToString() );
  }
}
```

And to add more information regarding my project, it is a Silverlight 5 application hosted in a ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

**NOTE:** I think that the solution Andy gave is probably good because I saw some similar awnsers elsewhere. I am just not sure that this is working with Azure...